# Cloud solution that doesn't take up disk space

Tags: disk-space, cloud-storage, icloud

I'm on a macbook running macOS Sierra with a hard drive capacity of 256gb and I'm running out of storage. I bought iCloud storage thinking that this would free up some disk space, but soon discovered that it just copies the files to the cloud and still keeps a local copy on my computer.

Is there any other solution where I can upload files to "the cloud" and not store them locally to free up disk space?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the local copy of the files now that they are on iCloud. Please refer to the Apple section of stackexchange:

[here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180212/can-i-delete-my-local-photo-library-now-that-all-my-photos-are-on-icloud)

Comment: I can't upload folders to iCloud via my web browser, so I can only copy folder to iCloud Drive via the finder and this will still take up disk space